# Is it possible to include Kivy program into wordpress?

Tags: python, wordpress, kivy

I wrote a kivy app. It was meant to be an app on my Iphone, but because I dont have a Mac and so cant create an IOS App, I thought of including the app in my website. It is made by wordpress.
Does anybody know, if and how it could be possible to include the program there?

I'm not the best programmer, so if there would be an easy way, that would be really great!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The best way would be to deploy it as PWA, but  it seem it's not really managable either https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/hmfj7l/deploy_kivy_app_as_a_web_app_possible_how/

Comment: Hm, sad. But thanks for your answer. So I have to try finding a Mac to create an App.

Comment: have a look into PWAs, they are like apps you can install directly from the website. ASFAIK you don't have to have a Mac for this or pay fees to apple.